# How do I make sections align in the output website

Tags: html, css

How do I make my sections align like the output picture?

I am struggling to find out how to make this works since using "fieldset" is something very fresh to me.
Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLPIc.png)

```css
fieldset.Content {
   height: 100px;
   width: 200px;
   margin-left: 70%;
}

label.extra {
   margin: auto;
}
```

```html
      <label class="extra">Rate this photo </br>
      <input type="number" min="1" max="10" name="rate" ></br>

      <label class="extra">Color Collection: </br>
      <input type="color" name="color" />

      <fieldset class="Content">
         <label>Date Taken: </label>
         <input type="date" name="date"></br>
         <label>Time Taken: </label></br>
         <input type="time" name="time">
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" />
      

   </fieldset>
```

Comment: Closing your `label` tags should be your first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per previous suggestion, here they are aligned using flexbox. For more info check out css-trick's [Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.photo-info-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: flex-start;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.date-taken {
  /* height: 100px; */
  width: 200px;
  /* margin-left: 70%; */
}
.extra {
  margin: auto;
}
.submit-buttons {
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="photo-info-container">
    <div>
        <label class="extra">Rate this photo </br>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="10" name="rate" ></br>

        <label class="extra">Color Collection: </br>
        <input type="color" name="color" />
    </div>

    <fieldset class="date-taken">
       <label>Date Taken: </label>
       <input type="date" name="date"></br>
       <label>Time Taken: </label></br>
       <input type="time" name="time">
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
<div class="submit-buttons">
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put Your Upper Contents in a div and your fieldset content in a div. then give flex to their parent container. you can check css-tricks flexbox tutorial https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by flex and also your label tags are not properly closed.please check below

```css
fieldset.Content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

label.extra {
  margin: auto;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.submit {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">
    <label class="extra">Rate this photo </br>
  <input type="number" min="1" max="10" name="rate" ></br></label>
    <label class="extra">Color Collection: </br>
      <input type="color" name="color" /></label></div>
  <fieldset class="Content">
    <label>Date Taken: </label>
    <input type="date" name="date"></br>
    <label>Time Taken: </label></br>
    <input type="time" name="time">
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="submit"> <input type="submit" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers with flexbox address the primary problem, but you really should avoid `<br>` tags for layout purposes, they are semantically meaningless and difficult to style. There are many options. The simplest of which is setting `label` and `input` to `display:block`. Now you can use media queries if you wanted to display them on one line on wide screens. Still doable with `br` but it's a lot more hacky.

Always make sure to close tags that aren't self-closing and if not wrapping the field with a `label` use `id` on the element and `for` on the label.

```css
/*Flex for our 2 components*/

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

/*Set label and inputs to block to display on seperate lines*/
.form-container input,
.form-container label {
  display: block;
}

/*Your existing style*/
fieldset.Content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

/*Center the submit button*/
[type=submit] {
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="form-info">
    <label class="extra" for="rate">Rate this photo </label>
    <input type="number" id="rate" min="1" max="10" name="rate">

    <label class="extra">Color Collection: </label>
    <input type="color" id="color" name="color" />
  </div>

  <fieldset class="Content meta-data">
    <label for="date">Date Taken: </label>
    <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
    <label for="time">Time Taken: </label>
    <input type="time" id="time" name="time">
  </fieldset>
</div>
<input type="submit" />
```